# What's the difference between NOT second preimage resistant and NOT collision resistant

Tags: hash, cryptography

By definition, Not 2nd-preimage resistant means: there exists at least one x (which is known) such that it is easy to find another x', such that h(x) = h(x').

While, Not collision resistant indicates: it is easy to find at least one such pair (x, x') that h(x) = h(x')

I don't see any difference here, anyone can tell? Or do I give the wrong definitions?

And, it is said that "Not collision resistant not necessarily means Not 2nd-preimage resistant", why is that?

Comment: See [this question and answers on Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/what-is-pre-image-resistance-and-how-can-the-lack-thereof-be-exploited).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theoretical cryptography, not programming as described in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Putting this into another answer because it's just too much to type for a comment.

The definition of 2nd-preimage-resistant is you have h(x) and x, and can't create x'.

The definition of preimage-resistant (without second!) means you have only h(x), and can't create x.

And the definition of collision resistant is you have nothing, and may choose any h(x), x and x'.

If you use the hash to sign a plaintext message, you need 2nd-preimage-resistancy, but not collision resistancy. It doesn't matter to you if someone can find two colliding messages that produce a hash that is different from yours, but you want to make sure noone is able to craft a *different* message that has the your hash, even if they know your plaintext.

If you use the hash to store hashed passwords, you don't care about collision resistance, and you don't care about 2nd-preimage-resistance, preimage-resistance is all you need. If an attacker knows one password, you don't really care if he can use that password to find a different one.

So these were two examples where collision resistance is not required, but preimage-resistance or 2nd-preimage-resistance is.

As to  "Not collision resistant not necessarily means Not 2nd-preimage resistant", why is that? , consider the hash function `if x has less then 24 bits, then h(x)=0, else h(x)=sha256(x)`. This is very obviously not collision resistant (choose any 2 words that have less than 4 letters), but, as long as your text is longer, this function is preimage-resistant and 2nd-preimage-resistant (assuming sha256 hasn't been broken yet).

Comment: Em... Two points:1, again, this is a very good answer and examples but not quite related to the last question I asked in the comment. To answer my question, please suggest a way to prove a hash is "NOT 2nd-preimage resistant" with minimum effort. My answer to this is: We know there exists a certain input x in this hash which allows me to easily get its 2nd preimage(a x' where h(x) = h(x')). We don't necessarily to know which x is. Do you agree with me? If yes, I can ask my follow-up questions.

Comment: And point 2: The last example hash function you gave, is actually not 2nd-preimage resistant. This property should not related to the input length. As long as we know there is some x which will lead to its 2nd-preimage, then we say this hash is Not-preimage resistant. (in this case, we know that for input "0", we can find one of its 2nd-preimage "00").

Comment: If you can find some kind of transformation on x, resulting in x', so that h(x)=h(x'), *for all possible values of x*, then the function isn't 2nd-preimage resistant, and of course not collision resistant. So, in your point 2, the hash function is 2nd-preimage-resistant, because the transformation only works on a very small subset of all possible x. As an example, h(x)="clear the 3rd bit on the 2nd byte of x, then calculate MD5". This isn't 2nd-preimage-resistant, with the transformation "toggle the 3rd bit on the 2nd byte".

Comment: Now I know where our disagreement lies. It's the definition of Not 2nd-preimage resistance. And I'm pretty sure mine is correct, because the negation of "given any x, there is no easy way to find its 2nd preimage" is "there exists AT LEAST ONE x, such that there is a easy way to find its 2nd preimage", otherwise the property of 2nd-preimage resistance is totally useless.

Answer (score 1):

2nd preimage resistant means, there's no (easy) way to find a 2nd x (called x') when you have only h(x), and maybe x.

Collision resistant means there's an (easy) way to find a random pair (x, x') with h(x)=h(x').

So the second one is weaker. Think about what happened to MD5 a while ago: there's an algorithm that finds pairs of input bytes that produce the same output. But this works only for specifically constructed input, not for random input. So, while it *is* possible to find messages that have a collision, the generic case "x is some specific message, find a second message that has the same MD5 as x" is not solved yet.

Comment: Thank you, but could you suggest a definition of a Non-2nd-preimage resisitant? That is what I'm asking.

Comment: Imagine a stupid hash function that just sums up the ascii codes of the input. It would translate Hello to 72+101+108+108+111=500. Knowing this hash, it's easy to find any number of input strings (for example oHell, heLlo, lolEh, ...) that yield the same hash.

Comment: Yeah, that's a particular instance of non-2nd-preimage resistant hash. But according to the definition, to break a 2-preimage resistant, we don't have to find a second preimage for every input x, we only need one x that can let us easily get another x' such that h(x) = h(x'), and any other inputs in the hash's domain is still "safe". Assume You are the attacker, you know my hash is not 2nd-preimage resistant, which means there must be a input x, which will be easy for you to find its 2nd-preimage. But as a attacker, you don't know which x it is, what benefit will you get from it??

Comment: The wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack explains it quite clearly. The Benefit is, for example, if the message is an SSL certificate. Creating a different certificate, which matches the MD5 key, will enable me to do man-in-the-middle attacks. Or, imagine the military use. You intercept a message "Bomb the enemy camp at 48N 33.3E as hard as you can", create a new message "Leave the camp at 48N 33.3E alone under all circumstances", that has the same hash, send the forged message to the destination, where it's taken for real because the hash matches.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I don't think you fully understand my question. In the example you gave, attacker seems know which two inputs share the same hash, but in the definition of Not 2nd-preimage resistant, what you only know is, there exists such input, but you don't know which x exactly. So, assume a hash exists only one x such that you can easily get the x' (which is necessary to say the hash is non-2nd-preimage resistant), but you don't know the x. Then, as the attacker, you have to search for the x first. And it comes out that you don't gain any benefit compare to Not collision resistant